# \tag is repeating equation number

Tags: numbering, align

I am trying to label and number one line in `align*` environment using `\tag{\theequation}` and it is just repeating the same equation number. It uses the previous equation number for all subsequent `\tag`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `align`? The starred form `align*` does not step the equation counter, that's why you get always the same number...

Comment: the starred display environments don't step the equation counter; you'd have to do that yourself.  you could use a numbered environment (no srat) and use `\notag` on all the unnumbered lines.  or you could show a minimum example that may indicate that quite another approach is really what you're looking for, say using `aligned` or `split`, either of which produces only one number for multiple lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, as the starred version of - `align*` - doesn't increment the `equation` counter. You'll have to do this manually:

```
\newcommand{\tagaligneq}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{align*}
  . & .. \\
  . & .. \tagaligneq \\
  . & .. \\
  . & .. \tagaligneq \\
  . & ..
\end{align*}
```

Of course, you can also use an opposite approach where all lines are numbered unless you use `\nonumber` inside an `align`:

```
\begin{align}
  . & .. \nonumber \\
  . & .. \\
  . & .. \nonumber \\
  . & .. \\
  . & .. \nonumber
\end{align}
```

Comment: hey thanks for taking time to answer this. this was a good help. now i understand the `*` better :)